# Dto to Entity conversion using MapStruct gives error

Tags: java, spring-boot, entity, dto, mapstruct

I am trying to create a mapper of "PersonDto" class to "PersonEntity" using [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org)

Please consider the following Entity, Dto and Mapper classes.

**PersonEntity.java**

```
package com.example.car;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PersonEntity {
    private String name;
    private List<CarEntity> cars;

    public PersonEntity() {
        cars = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean addCar(CarEntity carEntitiy) {
        return cars.add(carEntitiy);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<CarEntity> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(List<CarEntity> carEntities) {
        this.cars = carEntities;
    }
}
```

**CarEntity.java**

```
package com.example.car;

public class CarEntity {
    private String model;

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

**PersonDto.java**

```
package com.example.car;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PersonDto {
    private String name;
    private List<CarDto> cars;

    public PersonDto() {
        cars = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean addCar(CarDto carDto) {
        return cars.add(carDto);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<CarDto> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(List<CarDto> carDtos) {
        this.cars = carDtos;
    }
}
```

**CarDto.java**

```
package com.example.car;

public class CarDto {
    private String model;

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

**PersonMapper**

```
package com.example.car;

import org.mapstruct.CollectionMappingStrategy;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper(collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED)
public interface PersonMapper {

    PersonMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PersonMapper.class);

    PersonEntity personDtoToPersonEntity(PersonDto personDto);
}
```

When I am trying to generate code using the maven instructions provided at [this](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/installation/) link I am receiving the following error:

> Can't map property "java.util.List cars" to
>   "com.example.car.CarEntity cars". Consider to declare/implement a
>   mapping method: "com.example.car.CarEntity
>   map(java.util.List value)".

If i remove the "adder" method from Person classes it works fine. But I really want to use adder methods (for JPA entities parent child relationship purpose).

I am not sure why MapStruct not interpreting the cars property in PersonEntity as List. It is interpreting that property as a simple CarEntity and not the List of CarEntity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider mapping the "Has-A" property of your class too
Just include  **CarEntity carDtoToCarEntity(CarDto carDto)** 
Here is code snippet:

```
@Mapper(collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED)
public interface PersonMapper {
    PersonMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PersonMapper.class);
    CarEntity carDtoToCarEntity(CarDto carDto); 
    PersonEntity personDtoToPersonEntity(PersonDto personDto);

}
```

Let me know if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thanks. It's working nicely. But one thing I don't understand is that from 1.2.0 MapStruct support "Automatic creation of nested mapping methods" as described in [this](http://mapstruct.org/news/2017-10-18-mapstruct-1_2_0_Final-is-out) link. Currently I am using 1.3.0.Beta1. So why I need to define a mapping for nested property "cars"?

Comment: Did this work with 1.2.0? Yes there should be no need to create the `carDtoToCarEntity` method. Maybe this is a bug. Can you please open a ticket with your issue so we can have a look at it? 

Note: I am one of the members of the MapStruct team

Comment: @Filip I think the matching issue is already created. I added my comment there. Here is the [link](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1477).

Answer (score 0):

In your @Mapper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",uses = CarMapper.class)
```

annotation you should use mapper for any kind of nested type you have in your entity